# Root Reference After Loading External swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, external, root, loader

I am loading a game swf into my swf. However the preloader of the game (which is from a library) has a problem with the root when it tries to reference it. I assume this is because the root is now my main swf rather than the preloader swf. Does anyone know of a way to load a swf and allow it to keep its own root? It is much easier for me to change my loading code than the game preloader code.

Thank you!

Comment: What kind of problem/error are you getting? And how are you loading/adding the other swf to the display list.

Comment: There's quite a few mechanisms that can be used to load an external swf can you be more specific about the classes you're using for loading.  I'm more familiar with how this works in Flex but I would guess much of this translates down to pure AS3 as well http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-799a.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but this was a problem that I never really solved and had to do a workaround for by altering the code in the swf I was loading. I could find no other way to get it to reference the correct data.

Thank you all for you help though :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier if you reference the explicitly reference the main.swf root with a name and not "root" and then use "this" for the preloader.

For example, say if you document class is called Main (like Main.as).

Then in your Preloader MovieClip code...if you are writing a class for the preloader, do something like:

```
public function Preloader() {
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init, false, 0, true);               
}

private function init(e:Event):void {
    var main = (root as Main);

    // do stuff with "main here"
    main.addEventListner(...); // reference the main.swf
    this.addEventListener(...); // reference the preloader
}
```